# Selecting top level child

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add a class to the first level sections with jQuery and not other nested sections?

```
<div id="container">
    <section>
         <p>...</p>
    </section>
    <p>
         <section>
             <p>...</p>
         </section>
    </p>
    <section>
         <p>...</p>
    </section>
    <p>
         <section>
             <p>...</p>
         </section>
    </p>
</div>
```

```js
$('#container section:first-child').addClass('section');
```

It seems to be adding to the very first section only

Comment: what are all the sections that you need to select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [child selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('#container > section').addClass('section');
```

And on a side note, you can't nest `<p>` elements as it's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#container > section').addClass('section');
```